# ajax post from ajax get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to post on ajax from a ajax get.
Here is my code below that I'm using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/masterScreen/ajaxdealerpaid/{{$id}}", 
        type: "GET", 
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            document.getElementById("dealerPaid").innerHTML=data; 
        }
    });
});
```

And then i'm trying:

```
$(".pay").click(function(){
            alert('Order #'+id+' has been marked as paid for '+amountPaid+'');

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var amountPaid = $("#payAmount_"+id).val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "/masterScreen/dealermarkpaid/"+id+"/"+amountPaid, 
        type: "POST", 
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Order #'+id+' has been marked as paid for '+amountPaid+'');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

My HTML is...

```
<table style="width: auto;" class="table table-striped table-condensed" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <thead class="navbar-static-top" style="display:block; margin:0px; cell-spacing:0px; left:0px;">
              <tr>
                <th class="span2">Quote ID</th>
                <th class="span4">Customer name</th>
                <th class="span4">Connection date</th>
                <th class="span4">BDM</th>
                <th class="span4">Owed</th>
                <th class="span4">Amount</th>
                <th class="span2"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="dealerUnpaid" style="display:block; overflow:auto; max-height:400px;">

            </tbody>
            <tfoot id="dealerUnpaidtot" class="navbar-static-top" style="display:block; margin:0px; cell-spacing:0px; left:0px; font-weight: bold;">

            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

It displays the data from the first javascript, but I also have this code from the view it's GET from...

```
<td class="span4"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" class="payAmount" data=name="amount" data-id="{{$unpaid->id}}" id="payAmount_{{$unpaid->id}}"></td>

<td class="span2"><input type="button" class="btn pay" value="Pay" data-id="{{$unpaid->id}}"></td>
```

When I press the Pay button it doesn't do anything :/

Any help to make this work would be nice please.

Thanks guys

Comment: If clicking `.pay` does nothing you have an error in your script. Check the console.

Comment: "And then i'm trying" — How are you implementing that "And then"?

Comment: It shows nothing in console

Comment: change `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');` to `var id = $(this).data('id');` also, where is the `{{$id}}` coming from in the ajax url?

Comment: I tried to change the type of button - to an input and also the class names incase there's confliction but nothing. I have also tried the Javascript for the .pay in the page where the table data is generated and still nothing from it

Comment: {{$id}} is set as a variable for the particular view

Comment: "change var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); to var id = $(this).data('id');" doesn't change anything, still nothing and no error in console

Comment: When are you attaching the click event? if it's before the `success` of the GET has run, then no pay button will exist yet and $('.pay') will be empty. It should be done from the `success` function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're loading your markup (including the .pay element) using AJAX and then attempting to bind something to the .pay element's click event.  Since the .pay element doesn't exist in the page at the time you're doing the binding, the binding isn't working.  Change your binding from:

```
$('.pay').click(function(){
```

to

```
$(window).on('click', '.pay', function(){
```

That will attach the binding to the window, which has the effect of working even on elements that are added after the window is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".pay").click(function(){...
```

Works only on already create elements with class pay, it doesnt work on newly created elements by ajax call.
You can use delegate function to handle newly created elements

```
$("body").delegate(".pay","click",function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default handlings
    alert("Test");
    //do other code...

});
```